# Seeking file using c++

Tags: c++, string, file, gzip

```
void Test(Packets& packet)
{
      char buf[BUFLEN];
      char* offset = buf;
      unsigned int foo;
      for(;!gzeof(file_handle);){
            int len = gzread(file_handle, offset, sizeof(buf)-(offset-buf));
            char* cur = buf;
            char* end = offset+len;
            for (char* eol; (cur<end) && (eol = std::find(cur, end, '\n')) < end; cur = eol + 1)
            {
                string string_array = string(cur, eol);
                if(string_array[0] == 'L'){
                    packet.foo = blah;
                }else{
                    packet.foo = bar;
                }
                //After readnig a line.. how do I make sure it quits this function (does another job in some other function) and continous from the next line?
            }
#ifdef ROTATION
        offset = std::rotate(buf, cur, end);
#else
        offset = buf + (end-cur);
        std::rotate(buf, cur, end);
#endif
    }
    std::cout<<std::string(buf, offset) ;
}
```

After readnig a line.. how do I make sure it quits this function (does another job in some other function) and continous from the next line?
I tried to make buf, offset as global variables and read the file only when the buffer is empty.. it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to quit the function and continue from the next line?

Change your functions the way that one read a line and the other does whatever with it

somewhere you probably want to do something like or am i wrong?

```
{
Packets myPacket;
Test(packet);
OtherFunction(packet);
}
```

Comment: ok - so where could you make changes? just in function Test() ?

Comment: Try to make a call to the other function, which should work on the line, so you leave this scope without really quiting the function and you continue at the next line when you return

Comment: well, the functions that I'm caling are not global :). that's the issue :(

Comment: with the information you provided it is hard to say more. maybe you should show some more... including the context from which the functions you want to call, are called...

Comment: What exactly is required?